# Why does Apache server status show 150 processes only?

Tags: linux, configuration, server, apache2

Server RAM is **20GB**.
**Current Apache prefork module configuration:**

```
    StartServers          2 
    MinSpareServers      2
    MaxSpareServers      3
    ServerLimit         870
    MaxClients          870
    MaxRequestsPerChild   500000
```

As per configuration, Apache can handle 870 requests but it always show 150.
So, I thought reason for this to be wrong prefork configuration which leads to show only 150 requests every time but I can't find any issue in configurtaion.
Could you please let me the reason for why server status limits to 150 requests?
[image]